# JOptionPane Method Not found

Tags: java, swing

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.*;

public class icmp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

        int time = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            time = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter a time"));
            break;
        }

        time = time * 1000;
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputdialog("Enter the IP address");

        try
        {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(str);
            boolean test = addr.isReachable(time);

            if (test)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " Host isConnected", "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                JOption.showMessageDialog(null, str + "Host is not Connected", "Alert", JOption.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }
}
```

And here are the errors I'm getting:

```
icmp.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputdialog("Enter the IP address");
                                  ^
  symbol:   method showInputdialog(String)
  location: class JOptionPane
icmp.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                JOption.showMessageDialog(null,str+ "Host is not Connected","Alert",JOption.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable JOption
  location: class icmp
icmp.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                JOption.showMessageDialog(null,str+ "Host is not Connected","Alert",JOption.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                ^
  symbol:   variable JOption
  location: class icmp
3 errors
```

Answer (score 1):

What the compiler basically says is the following.

- There is no `showInputdialog` method in `JOptionPane` class. It's named as `showInputDialog` (Notice the capital 'D'). It is found in line 23 of your program.
- It (the compiler) cannot find the `JOption` class, it is called as `JOptionPane`. This is found in line 34 of your program.

Also, you are silently swallowing exceptions in your code, which is a very bad practice. Try to avoid that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling and case count:

*showInputdialog != showInputDialog*

Note that the latter is the correct way to call the method (Dialog being uppercase)